# convertir excel a pdf con PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Yo se que la libreria de PHPExcel ya esta obsoleta por lo que deberia unas spreadsheet de PHPOffice y ya la use me funciono excelente me hizo todo lo que queria incluyendo la conversion el problema es que el servidor donde almacenare el proyecto esta usando Apache2.4 y de PHP tiene la version 5.6.9 la cual no es compatible con PHPOffice por lo cual no me funciona el proyecto asi que lo tuve que adaptar a PHPExcel.

Generar.php

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';
//Para generar archivo Excel
require 'ClassesPhpExcel/PHPExcel.php';
require 'ClassesPhpExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

//$exa=$_POST['examen'];
//$aso=$_POST['asociado'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mst_useranswer,empleados WHERE idaso = 255603 AND test_id = 2 AND codigo_persona = 255603 AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9.5 HOUR) ORDER BY que_id ASC";
$resultado = $link->query($sql);

$s = "SELECT * FROM mst_test WHERE test_id = '2'";
$r = $link->query($s);

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

//while($raws = $r->fetch_assoc()){
  //  $name = $raws['test_name'];
//}
    $path = "examenes/Calidad.xlsx";
    $objPHPExcel = $reader->load($path);
 
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $fila_num = 10;
    $sumaTotal = 0;

    while($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        
            $sheet->setCellValue('B5', $rows['date']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('G4', $rows['Nombre']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('G5', $rows['codigo_persona']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $fila_num, $rows['your_ans']);
            $fila_num += 4;
            $sumaTotal += $rows['your_ans'];
            $sheet->setCellValue('I49', $sumaTotal);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C52', $rows['certificador']);
            if($sumaTotal < 10){
                $sheet->setCellValue('D53', 'NO');
            }else{
                $sheet->setCellValue('D53', 'SI');
            }
            if($sumaTotal < 10){
                $sheet->setCellValue('I53', 'SI');
            }else{
                $sheet->setCellValue('I53', 'NO');
            }
            $namefile = $rows['codigo_persona'];
            $nameperson = $rows['Nombre'];
    }

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
        $fecha = date('YmdHis');
    
        
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($sheet, 'Mpdf');
    $pdf_path = "$fecha$namefile.pdf";

    if (!file_exists('files')) {
        mkdir('files', 0755);
    }

    $writer->save('files/'.$pdf_path);

    $dir = 'files/';

    $new_name_file = $dir . $pdf_path;

    $ins = $link->query("INSERT INTO files(asociado,name_asoc,examen,url) VALUES ('$namefile','$nameperson','$name','$new_name_file')");

    if ($ins) {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("Se ha generado exitosamente");
        window.location.href='examen.php';
        </script>

        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("Ocurrio un problema");
        window.location.href='examen.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }


?>
```

El problema esta que cuando debe hacer la conversion a PDF me muestra el siguiente error en mi codigo.

`Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter() must be an instance of PHPExcel, instance of PHPExcel_Worksheet given, called in C:\Apache24\htdocs\ReportePreconteoMail\Generar2.php on line 61 and defined in C:\Apache24\htdocs\ReportePreconteoMail\ClassesPhpExcel\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php on line 129`.

Como puedo solucionar las falla como puedo realizar la renderizacion correctamente.

Comment: Tienes que indicarle a PHPExcel qué librería debe usar para crear el PDF. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21600948/5587982). Puede que tengas que adaptar el código según la librería de PDF que uses, la versión y la ubicación de las clases de tu librería.

Comment: Okey deja hago la prueba pro que no se si puedas ver las modificaciones que le hice a mi pregunta le implemente lo de esa respuesta y me daba otro error difernete al que puse ahorita

Comment: [Revisa el ejemplo de la doc, es más completo](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md#phpexcel_writer_pdf). Tienes que indicar la librería en los settings de PHPExcel. Adapta el código según la librería de PDF que estés usando y puedes usar las constantes predefinidas descritas en la columna `PHPExcel Internal Constant` de la tabla.

Comment: mi pregunta ahora es esa libreria donde la obtengo o como la declaro es que mi carpeta de PHPExcel dentro de ella en hay una carpeta llamada Witer y dentro de ahi hay una que se llama PDF y ahi se encuentran los siguientes archivos `Core`, `DomPDF`,`mPDF`,`tcPDF` pero  cuando declaro esta libreria `$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../libraries/PDF/' . $rendererLibrary;` el sistema me arroja el siguiente error `Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values as appropriate for your directory structure`.

Comment: ¿Qué has declarado para `$rendererName`?